# ReactJS - change attr value on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing a web app using the ReactJS framework.

I am trying to write an event that when I click on one element in a set it changes the value of the selected attribute to true and sets the remaining elements to false.

```
<NavigationButton to="/" label="Dashboard" exact>
<MenuItem className={classes.menuItem} selected={true/false}>
    <ListItemIcon className={classes.icon}>
        <Home />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText classes={{ primary: classes.primary }} inset primary="Strona główna" />
</MenuItem>
</NavigationButton>
<NavigationButton to="/payment" label="Payment" exact>
<MenuItem className={classes.menuItem} selected={true/false}>
    <ListItemIcon className={classes.icon}>
        <Payment />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText classes={{ primary: classes.primary }} inset primary="Moje płatności" />
</MenuItem>
</NavigationButton>
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is to encompasses all of your components in a stateful component that will track which of your elements is selected or not. This component will then have a function (something like `handleClick`) that will take in that press button class and `setState` changing to the element that should be selected now. Now you can pass down the function and the state (what is currently suppose to be selected) as props to the children elements and onClick on, it will trigger a callback to the parent component telling it to `setState`. Then in each of the individual components, you can just check to see if the prop `this.props.currentSelect === ${name of the element}` to see if they element should be selected or not

```
// some jsx file
class StatefulComponent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentlySelect: "someMenuItem"
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(str){
    this.setState({
      currentlySelect: str
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <React.Fragment>
        <NavigationButton to="/" label="Dashboard" exact>
          <MenuItem handleClick={this.handleClick} currentlySelect={this.state.currentlySelect}  className={classes.menuItem} selected={true / false}>
            <ListItemIcon className={classes.icon}>
              <Home />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText classes={{ primary: classes.primary }} inset primary="Strona główna" />
          </MenuItem>
        </NavigationButton>
        <NavigationButton to="/payment" label="Payment" exact>
          <MenuItem handleClick={this.handleClick} currentlySelect={this.state.currentlySelect} className={classes.menuItem} selected={true / false}>
            <ListItemIcon className={classes.icon}>
              <Payment />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText classes={{ primary: classes.primary }} inset primary="Moje płatności" />
          </MenuItem>
        </NavigationButton>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `selected` of type `number` supplied to `MenuItem`, expected `boolean`.

Comment: Well i didn't give you the correct syntax, just a little bit of boilerplate to get started